# problem landing

Tags: elite-dangerous

I am not able any more to request landing on any station. The stations were targeted, I was not in supercruise, I was located 1000-2000 metres away from the stations respectively and my weapons have been retracted, but in the "Contacts" tab nothing was listed, so I was not able to request landing. I have checked my module tab to my sensors but I cant activate then I have also tried to turn something off for maybe I didn't have enough power but still not working.

[image: Screenshot of ship console]

Comment: A screenshot of your contacts tab might help as well.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the screenshot. Your sensor module is destroyed(health 0%) and needs to be repaired before you can activate it again. Here are the steps you need to take in order to start the repair sequence.

1. Go to the right panel (where you are now)
2. Select the Ship Tab
3. Scroll down to Reboot/Repair
4. Select it
5. wait for the sequence to finish
6. Go back to modules
7. Turn on Sensor